# Helper VS Library in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have controller `Cars`. Lets call this entity Cars.

Each car has type: `0 => car, 1 => truck` etc.

The model `Car` contents fields:

```
id | type | engine
1      1      2
```

So, from this table I know that car is truck by `type` field.

When I get all rows from table Cars:

```
$cars = Cars:all();
```

I take field type in format integer, but I need to get string, instead 1 I sholud get `Truck`.

I have some ways to do that:

- Use  `with()` and connect table car with table type_car
- Use Helper Class, which gets all type_Car in array, after returns item by key in array
- Use Library in Laravel that the same as Helper

What do you recommend me to use?

Answer (score 0):

This would be an example of using relationships. A car would have a 'Type', which would be another table called `types`. You would change the `type` field to `type_id` (default way eloquent saves relationships - there are ways to change this, but I would recommend using this way).

```
class Car extends Model {

    public function type() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Type');
    }
}

class Type extends Model {

    public function cars() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Car');
    }
}
```

Comment: And how call this in model car?

Comment: you would call `$car = Car::with('type')->find(1);` -- then access the type with `$car->type->name` (depending on the properties of your `Type` model.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$car->type()`, and you will get the type, note that you need to create another entity called Type containing the `id` and the `type_description` or something like that